# Transient variable inherited and subclass is serialized

Tags: java, serialization, transient

If transient variable from a Serializable class is inherited and if i change the value of the variable in subclass.

Is transient variable inherited as transient only?
What will happen if sub class is deserialized? Will the transient variable maintain its behavior and have the default value after deserialize subclass.

Answer (score 5):

fields cannot be inherited, they can only be hidden.  If you have a `transient` field in a super class it behaves exactly the same as it would if you serialized the class.

> Will the transient variable maintain its behavior and have the default value after deserialize subclass.

yes. You can test this fairly easily, but it will always do this.