# Why is it possible to declare transient variables in abstract class in java?

Tags: java

Since abstract class and interface cannot be instantiated hence serialization is not applicable, however
what is the purpose of allowing transient variables in abstract class?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Java have transient fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910374/why-does-java-have-transient-fields)

Comment: What if you are serializing a child class? You would be okay with Java implicitly only serializing half your object, would you? That sounds like desirable behaviour, does it?

Comment: I think this will make it more clear https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36351555/transient-variable-inherited-and-subclass-is-serialized

Answer (score 1):

Because somebody might create a subclass that is *not* abstract and then instantiate it.